# What is software reverb?

Tags: reverb

I was told to "put a microphone inside a guitar, and run it through **software reverb**".

What is this?

Answer (score 3):

Though I've never heard anyone refer to as "software reverb" before, I'm fairly certain you were being told to record the dry guitar and then add in reverb and ambience using a plugin effect in your computer software you used to record the sound. Reverb plugins for software recording solutions come in all shapes and sizes and can use a few different techniques to give you reverb using an algorithm instead of doing in the old fashioned way and, you know, actually recording a space and waves bouncing off physical things.

If you elaborate on what software you're recording with more specific help on how to use reverb in that piece of software can be given.

Answer (score 2):

Put in other words, "record the guitar uisng a mic, and then put a reverb effect on the recording using software."

As opposed to, say, putting a reverb effect on the recording using a hardware effect unit, or using a recording room with a reverb sound that you like.

I'm assuming you're already pretty familiar with reverb.  If not, [Wikipedia's Reverb page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverb) has a pretty good summary at the top.